# tr1::hash for uint64_t

Tags: c++, linux, tr1

I'm trying to hash a 64 bit integer,

```
uint64_t temp = ...;
return tr1::hash<uint64_t>(temp);
```

However I get the error,

```
error: no matching function for call to ‘std::tr1::hash<long long unsigned int>::hash(uint64_t&)’
```

Why doesn't this work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`hash` is a *class*. You have to make an object:

```
return std::tr1::hash<uint64_t>()(temp);
//                            ^^^^
```